# Dagger, how to inject a class, not a module

Tags: android, dagger

According to JakeWharton's slide 97 at https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/2014, the object graph allows injecting a class. 
However, I did try and I got an NPE, seems that the constructor of the said class is never called.

My code is as follow. I have no trouble with `AppModule`, which provides `AnalyticsManager`.

```
public class App extends Application implements ModuleCreator {
private ObjectGraph objectGraph;
@Inject
AnalyticsManager analyticsManager;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    objectGraph.inject(RealBusEvent.class);
    objectGraph.inject(Trip.class);
    objectGraph.inject(this);
    analyticsManager.registerAppEnter();
}
public List<Object> getModules() {
    return Arrays.<Object>asList(new AppModule(this));
}
}
```

The other 2 classes:

```
public class RealBusEvent {
     @Inject Trip trip;

     @Inject
     public RealBusEvent(){; }

     public Trip getTrip() {
         return trip;
     }
}

public class Trip {
    @Inject
    public Trip(){
        this.time = 123;
    }

    public Trip(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    private long time;
}
```

And the class consuming `RealEventBus` is like below:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject RealBusEvent event;

    TextView mTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(event.getTrip().getTime()));
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

I the object `event` is always null. Am I missing anything? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On every class you need to perform a `@Inject` you have to call: `objectGraph.inject(this);`  usually you put it in the constructor, like this:

```
public class RealBusEvent {
     @Inject Trip trip;

     @Inject
     public RealBusEvent(){
       YOU_OBJECTGRAPH_REFERENCE.inject(this);
     }

     public Trip getTrip() {
         return trip;
     }
}
```

The main challenge is 'How to get the **YOU_OBJECTGRAPH_REFERENCE**' if you don't have a 'Context'. For that you can make the `ObjectGraph` accessible via a Singleton, not very elegant, but sometimes it's the only alternative if you can't pass the `Context`.

But if you do have a `Context`, you can just follow the example on this link:
 https://github.com/nuria/android-examples/tree/master/dagger-logger-example/Sample/src/com/example/android/ui

And see **how** they make the `ObjectGraph` (defined int the `DemoApplication`) be accessible from `DemoBaseActivity`.